# How to convert a Future[Vector[UserLocation]] to a Future[Vector[User]]

Tags: scala, future

I have a method below that I want to return `Future[Vector[user]]`.

The method `userLocationService.getUserLocationsInList` will return a `Future[Vector[UserLocation]]`.

where UserLocation looks something like:

```
case class UserLocation(id: Int, locationId: Int, userId: Int)


def getUsersInLocation(locationIdList: Set[Int]): Future[Vector[User]] = {

   userLocationService.getUserLocationsInList(locationIdList).map{
      userLocations =>
          // ????????????
   }

}
```

I have a method that returns a single User based on UserId like:

```
userService.getById(userId: Int): Future[User]
```

How can I build a Future[Vector[User]] given the above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you `map` the `Future[Vector[UserLocation]]`, you can easily generate a `Vector[Future[User]]` within, from the contained `Vector[UserLocation]`:

```
userLocations.map(location => userService.getById(location.userId))
```

You can use `Future.sequence` to invert the `Vector[Future[User]]` to a `Future[Vector[User]]`:

```
Future.sequence(userLocations.map(location => userService.getById(location.userId)))
```

Or use `Future.traverse`:

```
Future.traverse(userLocations) { location => userService.getById(location.userId) }
```

This would leave you with a `Future[Future[Vector[User]]]`, which can be fixed by changing the `map` to a `flatMap`. Putting it all together:

```
def getUsersInLocation(locationIdList: Set[Int]): Future[Vector[User]] = {
  userLocationService.getUserLocationsInList(locationIdList).flatMap { locations =>
    Future.traverse(locations) { location =>
      userService.getById(location.userId)
    }
  }
}
```

Or with a for-comprehension:

```
def getUsersInLocation(locationIdList: Set[Int]): Future[Vector[User]] = {
  for {
    locations <- userLocationService.getUserLocationsInList(locationIdList)
    users <- Future.traverse(locations) { location =>
      userService.getById(location.userId)
    }
  } yield users
}
```

Comment: sorry!  The getById returns a Future[Option[User]] not Future[User].  Does that complicate things?

Comment: @Blankman Then you'll get a `Vector[Option[User]]` which you can just call `flatten` on. i.e. `yield users.flatten`. _Assuming_, you just want to discard the cases where you get `None`.

Comment: Thanks it worked, I did the 2nd version and yield users.flatten.  Just out of curiosity, how would I flatten the users in the flatMap version? I tried assigning everything to a val and calling users.flatten but that didn't work.

Comment: @Blankman You would have to `map` the result of `Future.traverse`, and flatten that. i.e. `Future.traverse { ... }.map(_.flatten)`